# unable to connect to WSL container by it's ip address

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, iptables, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When I do `php -S localhost:80` in WSL / Ubuntu 20.04.1 I am able to connect inside WSL but not outside of WSL.

My WSL instance has an eth0 IP address of 172.18.240.175 as doing ifconfig reveals. If I'm inside the container I can connect to port 80 without issue (eg. `php -r "fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 80);"`) but, outside of the container but whilst still on the Windows 11 WSL host, I am unable to connect. `php -r "fsockopen('172.18.240.175', 80);"` gives me the following:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 172.18.240.175:80 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
) in php shell code on line 1
```

For good measure I did this:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, when I do `sudo iptables -nL -v | grep 80` I see this:

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    5   260 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

(well, technically, the grep only returns the second line, but whatever)

In fact, every time I try to make an HTTP request, the pkts and bytes columns each go up. So the WSL instance is receiving the request in some manner but it's then being denied. I'd use Wireshark to capture the packets but idk how to use Wireshark to capture what's being sent through WSL...

When I do `sudo ufw status verbose` it says `Status: inactive`. None-the-less, I tried `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` and it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"actively refused it" typically means TCP RST, sent by the responding system to indicate that *no service is listening* on that address:port.

Listening sockets aren't bound only to a (destination) port, they're bound to a (destination) IP address:port, and when you're using `-S localhost:80` you're asking PHP to [bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php) the listener to `[::1]` or `127.0.0.1` specifically.

You can see this in the output of `ss -l sport 80` or `netstat -ln`.

Use `[::]:80` or `0.0.0.0:80` for the "all local addresses" wildcard address for IPv6 or IPv4 respectively. (The former, on Linux, will accept both.)

```
php -S "0.0.0.0:80"
php -S "[::]:80"
```

> I'd use Wireshark to capture the packets but idk how to use Wireshark to capture what's being sent through WSL...

WSL version 2 "containers" are a full Hyper-V VM with their own network interfaces and you can use `tcpdump` inside the VM to see what's being received. On the host, you also have a (slightly hidden) Hyper-V vSwitch interface that's handling the routing and NAT for 172.18.240.0/24, and Wireshark should be able to see it as well.

Comment: _Use `[::]:80` or `0.0.0.0:80` for the "all local addresses" wildcard address for IPv6 or IPv4 respectively. (The former, on Linux, will accept both.)_ What would be the command to do that?

Comment: `php -S 0.0.0.0:80`, for example.

Comment: oh - i thought you meant to do that for iptables. Anyway, I tried that and it worked - thanks!!